# How to map character to numeric position in java?

Tags: java

E.g.

- input: ['A', 'Z', 'F', 'D', ...]
- output: [0, 25, 5, 3, ...]

In C I'd just subtract the char from 'A', but I don't seem to be able to do this in java.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do simple math with chars in Java as well:

```
    System.out.println('A' - 'A');
```

will output 0.

Comment: Note that those must be characters, not Strings. The single quotes are important.

Comment: This will return bogus values for characters outside of the domain. The code is fragile.

Comment: "This will return bogus values for characters outside of the domain.". So will the C equivalent.

Comment: @Stefan - the entire problem (as posed by the OP) is fragile.  The notion of a "numeric position of a character" is loaded with assumptions about character sets, assumptions about what is a valid character, etc, etc.  Bear in mind that he is coming from a C background ...

Comment: @Stefan, this is well-defined... Java uses UTF-16 characters, and the letters 'A'...'Z' are within an ASCII-compatible range.

Comment: You don't understand. A function written like this expects invariants (characters 'A'-'Z'), but it does not define these invariants programmatically.

Comment: @Stefan: if you add a simple `result = (result < 0 || result > 25) ? -1 : result` this method returns exactly the same result as your proposed solution.

Answer (score 30):

Use the `indexOf` method on a String object.  For example,

`"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".indexOf('F')`

returns 5.

Comment: If you do not require the range checks, 'F' - 'A' is faster, though.

Comment: Don't forget to account for error cases -- if indexOf returns -1, that means it was given a character not in the string (in this case, something besides an upper-case letter).

Comment: Thilo -- not appreciably.  The size of the search domain is limited to 26 characters; computers are fast.  I just ran a quick check on my desktop machine; for the worst case (finding 'Z') my method does it in 5 ms and yours does it in 1 ms.  (In fact, those numbers hold no matter what letter we're searching for; with this tiny search domain, both methods are effectively constant-time.)

If this is happening a zillion times, then yeah, you'll want to shave that off -- but otherwise I think you're optimizing prematurely.

Comment: Actually, you can do the range check with 'F' - 'A' as well, just see if the result is between 0 to 25.

Comment: You could use a hashmap to obtain a similar result, with (perhaps) better execution time. Do you really need 4 milliseconds? If so, you can probably benefit from other optimizations, such as caching.

Comment: actually the issue that by doing this you are repeatedly creating a new string every time.  object creation is a relatively slow process, I'll put the enum based solution in a moment which should be higher performance

Comment: Is these functions Case Insensitive? I need it to return A-1 also a-1 , B-2 b - 2

Answer (score 6):

actually the weak point of the other solutions here is that they involve string creation

```
public enum Alphabet {
    A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z
}
```

you can now use the ordinal function to get the offset in here.  e.g. Alphabet.L.ordinal();

However, since I assume you are dealing with functions, here is a more useful definition

```
public enum Alphabet {
    A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z;

    public static int getNum(String targ) {
        return valueOf(targ).ordinal();
    }

    public static int getNum(char targ) {
        return valueOf(String.valueOf(targ)).ordinal();
    }    
}
```

Notes: unlike other languages, you can declare an enum in it's own file exactly like a class.  Actually enums as shown above can contain fields and methods too, the fields are statically created, and are very hard to break.  In fact the use of an enum with only local methods and variables and a single enum type called INSTANCE is the recommended way to create a singleton as it is unbreakable even by reflection.

You may want to think about slipping a toUppercase() call in there too if you are not controlling the calls to the function

If you are looking to more dynamically create your alphabet rather than use a predefined alphabet, you should be looking into maps

Answer (score 2):

The output you are expecting is just the `offset` of a upper case letter with respect to `'A'`. So just subtract the Unicode value of `'A'` from the unicode value of the letter whose offset is needed.

example: `'B' - 'A' = 1`

Comment: @Stefan: I'll apply the above only for uppercase letters. Not for any char.

Comment: "Inherently wrong" is a bit strong. It assumes the input to be from the proper range, but there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Actually, even with an invalid input, nothing bad happens. You just get a number outside of the range 0..25, which is exactly the same as with the indexOf() solution.

Comment: ...but it allows others to easily break the method. A function written like this does not guarantee the invariants it expects. It's breakable, flimsy, and a poor man's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's different implementation which runs in logarithmic time:

**Class**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class CharacterIndex {
    private char[] characters = new char[]{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    public int index(char character) {
        assert characters != null;
        return Arrays.binarySearch(characters, Character.toUpperCase(character));                
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;

public class CharacterIndexTest {
    private CharacterIndex characterIndex;
    @Before
    public void createIndex() {
        characterIndex = new CharacterIndex();
    }
    @Test
    public void testIndexOfLetterA() {
        assertEquals(0, characterIndex.index('A'));
        assertEquals(0, characterIndex.index('a'));
    }
    @Test
    public void testNotALetter() {
        assertEquals(-1, characterIndex.index('1'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `java.lang.Character.toUpperCase('a') - 65;`

Answer (score -1):

```
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
return alphabet.indexOf( myChar );
```

Comment: @Stefan, that is a terrible solution, since you are searching linearly through the alphabet. Sure, it is constant time because you have a fixed-size alphabet, but it is unnecessarily slow.

Comment: Also, -1 for downvoting everyone else. That is just obnoxious.

Comment: Then use a map of character to number value. This solution requires 26 character comparisons (13 on average), versus a call to hashcode, so there are minor savings at best in terms of speed.