# How to get numeric position of alphabets in java?

Tags: java

How to get numeric position of alphabets in java ?

Suppose through command prompt i have entered abc then as a output i need to get 123 how can i get the numeric position of alphabets in java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java characters are stored as numbers. Read about ASCII numbers, you can do math on characters.

Comment: By "numeric position of alphabets", do u mean the position of an alphabet in the word?

Comment: I think he means the position of a character in the English alphabet. a=1, b=2, c=3 etc

Comment: numeric position of alphabet characters in both small and capital A-1 and a-2 like  Z-26 and z-26.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
String str = "abcdef";
char[] ch  = str.toCharArray();
for(char c : ch){
    int temp = (int)c;
    int temp_integer = 96; //for lower case
    if(temp<=122 & temp>=97)
        System.out.print(temp-temp_integer);
}
```

Output:

> 123456

@Shiki for Capital/UpperCase letters use the following code:

```
String str = "DEFGHI";
char[] ch  = str.toCharArray();
for(char c : ch){
    int temp = (int)c;
    int temp_integer = 64; //for upper case
    if(temp<=90 & temp>=65)
        System.out.print(temp-temp_integer);
}
```

Output:

> 456789

Answer (score 31):

Another way to do this problem besides using ASCII conversions is the following:

```
String input = "abc".toLowerCase();
final static String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for(int i=0; i < input.length(); i++){
    System.out.print(alphabet.indexOf(input.charAt(i))+1);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Convert each character to its ASCII code, subtract the ASCII code for "a" and add 1. I'm deliberately leaving the code as an exercise.

This sounds like homework. If so, please tag it as such.

Also, this won't deal with upper case letters, since you didn't state any requirement to handle them, but if you need to then just lowercase the string before you start.

Oh, and this will only deal with the latin "a" through "z" characters without any accents, etc.

Answer (score 7):

```
char letter;
for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
{
    letter = text.charAt(i);
    if(letter>='A' && letter<='Z')
        System.out.println((int)letter - 'A'+1);
    if(letter>='a' && letter<= 'z')
        System.out.println((int)letter - 'a'+1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the alphabet but for the english one, try this:

```
String input = "abc".toLowerCase(); //note the to lower case in order to treat a and A the same way
for( int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
   int position = input.charAt(i) - 'a' + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String word = "blah blah";

for(int i =0;i<word.length;++i)
{

if(Character.isLowerCase(word.charAt(i)){
System.out.print((int)word.charAt(i) - (int)'a'+1);
}
else{
System.out.print((int)word.charAt(i)-(int)'A' +1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to write a loop to iterate over the characters in the string. Take a look at the [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class which has methods to give you its [`length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) and to find the [`charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) at each index.

For each character, you need to work out its numeric position. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564541/how-to-map-character-to-numeric-position-in-java) to see how this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

just logic I can suggest take two arrays.

one is Char array

and another is int array.

convert ur input string to char array,get the position of char from char and int array.

dont expect source code here