# Java: Next character in String

Tags: java, loops, character

I have one String generated of random characters that will encrypt another String given by the user by adding the first character from the String with the first character of the given String. It's working fine, but if the user were to enter multiple words with spaces in between, I want to choose the next character of the first String rather than code the space itself. Is that possible? This is what I have:

(random is the coded string and sentenceUpper is string given by user)

```
public static void encrypt(String sentenceUpper){

String newSentence = "";

for(int i = 0; i < sentenceUpper.length(); i++){
 char one = random.charAt(i);
 char two = sentenceUpper.charAt(i);

 if(one < 'A' || one > 'Z'){
  two = sentenceUpper.charAt(1 + i);}

 char result = (char)((one + two)%26 + 'A');
 newSentence += "" + result;
```

}

EDIT FOR BETTER EXPLANATION:

I have:

String random = "WFAZYZAZOHS";

I would like to code user input:

String upperCase: "YOU GO";

So, I'm going to take Y + L = U, etc...
to get :
"UTUSEN
"
But I see that there's a space in "YOU GO" , So I'd like to change it to:
 WFA ZY + YOU GO = UTU SE.

I hope that's better explained.

Comment: Could you explain your question in better detail please? I do not understand what you are trying to do here

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper, does that help a bit?

Comment: Why Y+L? It shouldn't be Y+W?

Comment: It may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879714/how-to-get-numeric-position-of-alphabets-in-java . If I understood, you may use numbers to respresent letters, it would make easier to deal with sums.

Comment: Im afraid I still dont understand. like Arthur said, why did you do Y+L? shouldn't it be Y+W?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would probably be to use an `if` statement to run the code in the loop only if the character is not a space. If you don't want to skip the character in the random string, you would need a separate variable to track the current character index in that string.

Example: Put this after defining `one` and `two` and put the rest of the loop inside it:

```
if(two==' '){
    ...
}
```

Then, add the space in the output:

```
else{
    newSentence+=" ";
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a coded example of what you are saying?

Comment: Do you want to skip the character in the random string as well as the input string if a space is reached?

Comment: I'd post that comment in the question section so that the OP can see it

Comment: @kittycat3141, yes, that's exactly what I mean. When a space is reached in user input, I'd like to skip a character in the random string rather than encode the space.