# Encryption method not outputting correctly

Tags: java, class, loops, methods, int

I have a class called `encryption`which represents a String that my user enters in the main, which is then encrypted by my `.encryptMessage()` method. I want to have the characters of the alphabet be turned into their corresponding `int` values and vice versa with the `int` values. I thought my method would do this properly but it is not outputting in that way.

**Question: How can I fix this method to make the alphabet `chars` output as their corresponding `int` values and vice versa? (i.e. a = 1, b = 2, 1 = a, 2 = b, etc)**

```
public class Encryption {

private String message;

public Encryption(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String encryptMessage()
{
    char messageChar = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
    {
        messageChar = message.charAt(i);
        messageChar = Character.toUpperCase(messageChar);

        if (Character.isLetter(messageChar))
        {
            int charValue = Character.getNumericValue(messageChar);
            message += charValue;
        }

        else if (Character.isDigit(messageChar))
        {
            int messageVal = 0;
            messageChar = (char) messageVal;
            message += (char) messageVal;
        }

    }
    return message;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Character.getNumericValue` does not return the numeric value you think it is.

> The java.lang.Character.getNumericValue(char ch) returns the int value
>   that the specified Unicode character represents. For example, the
>   character '\u216C' (the roman numeral fifty) will return an int with a
>   value of 50.

Here a snippet that would work

```
String str = "abcdef";
char[] ch  = str.toCharArray();
for(char c : ch)
{
    int temp = (int)c;
    int temp_integer = 96; //for lower case
    if(temp<=122 & temp>=97)
       System.out.print(temp-96);
}
```

This one would work for `Capital` letters

```
String str = "DEFGHI";
char[] ch  = str.toCharArray();
for(char c : ch)
{
    int temp = (int)c;
    int temp_integer = 64; //for upper case
    if(temp<=90 & temp>=65)
        System.out.print(temp-temp_integer);
}
```

Note that these two snippets are stolen from [How to get numeric position of alphabets in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879714/how-to-get-numeric-position-of-alphabets-in-java)

Comment: Also, how would I go about doing this then in the opposite way? Say if I wanted an individual integer to be turned into its corresponding letter?

Comment: @Jordan simply add the `temp_integer` instead of substracting it, then output the int value as a char.