# how to convert a letter in a string to a number and count it to get total

Tags: java, string

I'm quite new to Java so I am wondering how to convert a letter in a string to a number and count it to get total like this D=4, o = 15, n= 14, a= 1, l=12, d=4 à Total = 50, can anybody help me ? i really need the answer

Comment: you should show your effort. Try then ask. We are not here to do your homework

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get numeric position of alphabets in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879714/how-to-get-numeric-position-of-alphabets-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

If you like to assign value 1 to A, 2 to B and so on you can do the following:

```
String myName = "Donald".toUpperCase();
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myName.length(); i++) {
    char ch = myName.charAt(i);
    int value = ch - 'A' + 1;   // Here is the trick
    total += value;
}
System.out.println("Total: " + total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int stringValue(String string){
     int sum=0;
     for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
     char ch = string.charAt(i);
        sum+=getCharVaulue(ch);
    }
    return sum;
}

public static int getCharVaulue(char ch){
    ch = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
    return ch - 96;
}
```