# How to write a program to get three inputs from a user: a string (convert to numbers), an int and a double and add their values

Tags: java

I need to write a program that requests and accepts three inputs from a user- a string, an int and a double.
The program should pass the inputs to a method that converts the string to its equivalent numeric value and adds this value to the sum of the remaining inputs. The program should display the result to the user.

The letter a is worth 1, b worth 2, all the way up to the letter z being worth 26.
If it contains a digit, the value of that character is the value of the digit itself, 0 is worth 0, 1 worth 1, all the way up to 9 worth 9.
Any other character in the string (for example: !$?*&^%) is worth 0.

What I have so far is in my code below

import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
            Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter a string");



            String input1 = myObj.nextLine();

            if (!input1.matches("[a-zA-Z_]+!$?*&^%")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid String");
            }
                else { 
                System.out.println("Please enter a integer"); 
            }



            int input2 = myObj.nextInt();



            System.out.println("Please enter a double");

            double input3 = myObj.nextDouble();
        }

    }
```

Sample output
Please enter a string: dad6!
Please enter an integer: 10
Please enter a decimal number: 2.5
Result is: 27.5

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: How to write a program that requests and accepts three inputs from a user- a string, an int and a double. The program should pass the inputs to a method that converts the string to its equivalent numeric value and adds this value to the sum of the remaining inputs. The program should display the result to the user.

Comment: StackOverflow answers questions, it does not code for you. About "converting" letters to numbers, take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564541/how-to-map-character-to-numeric-position-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    float charSum=0;

            Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter a string");
            String input1 = myObj.nextLine();
            char[] arr=input1.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
               int ascii=(int)arr[i];

               if(ascii>=97&&ascii<=122){
                charSum=charSum+ascii-96; //for a-z
               } 
                else if(ascii>=65&&ascii<=90){
                charSum=charSum+ascii-64;  //for A-Z
                }
                else if(ascii>=48&&ascii<=57){
                     charSum=charSum+ascii-48;  //ascii for number
                }else{
                     charSum=charSum+0;  //ascii for special Character
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Please enter a Integer");
            int integerValue = myObj.nextInt();
            charSum+=integerValue;

            System.out.println("Please enter a Double");
            Double doubleValue = myObj.nextDouble();
            charSum+=doubleValue;

            System.out.println(charSum);

    }
}
```

> here,I have taken string and find out the ascii value of each and subtracted 96 because the ascii value of a-> 97 .A->65 (so if a needs to be 1 it must be 97-96=1) and for special characters as you asked it to be 0 so added that to the sum variable.Since the double is also and input so the output can be either float or double .I have taken float.Hope this solution solves your query

**https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler**  can check the code on this compiler online.

Comment: Thank you ! wow very impressive I hope some day I can be as good as you Ayushi, what would you recommend as the best resources to learn Java? @Ayushi Keshri

Comment: @Nexus_Valentine Kindly, approve the answer (it makes newbie easy to rely on answers) For java : I have studied from udemy and online youtube tutorials you can also go through basics from w3School :https://www.w3schools.com/java/ and javaTpoint: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial they have best resources available.

Comment: Answer is approved was there a particular course from udemy you found the best?

Comment: i have cleared my concept from youtube vdos in my language.I have practiced one project from udemy and have been working on java since 1 year..basic is easy..try to solve coding problems.